# Having problems getting divs to line up properly

Tags: css

I'm having problems getting some divs to display inline. I've tried a bunch of things but nothing is working correctly. How do y'all normally do it? Floating them? Putting them in a list and lining that up? Maybe I'm not thinking of something =/

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe post a screenshot of the layout you're going for.

Comment: Ok well I figured out the problem but still am working on a solution.

I am trying to get several divs into a larger "window" div and only display what is in the window. So I adjusted the "window" div to a fixed width and set overflow to hidden to hide the rest inside. However, when I set a fixed width, the div's inside don't line up "inline" anymore, rather stack vertically.

Comment: Oh and I'm going for a "slideshow" type effect by shifting over the position of the divs inside. Only the stuff in the window dimensions will show.

Comment: #rightwindow {width:458px;height:694px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;padding:0px;border:1px solid #333333;}
#rightslider {height:694px;position:relative;}
.projecttab {float:left;}

Comment: #rightwindow is the window / #rightslider is the div containing the smaller divs that will slide left to right / .projecttab are the individual tabs inside the slider

Comment: Please edit your post instead so we can have syntax hilight :(

Comment: post the html and css in the actual question with the edit button :D

Answer (score 1):

DIVs are "block" elements by default. If you want inline behaviour, use the style element "display: inline"

-Oisin

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it with float, absolute positioning, or tables (not reccommended for layout). Have a look at some tutorials, here's one that'll get you started :D

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/